# Can a 6V DC circuit turn on a separate/unconnected DC circuit?

Tags: switches, dc, inductor, low-power

Can a 6 VDC circuit be configured to switch on a second, separate 3 VDC circuit?

I had thought that an inductor's magnetic field could be used to close a normally-off reed switch, as illustrated in the image below. I looked into it but became more confused. What I found seems to be saying that an inductor does literally nothing in a DC circuit, as though it's not even there...or have I misunderstood something?

The context of this is: I'm making lit miniature buildings as gifts (see diagram below). Its music-box mechanism is purely mechanical and the voltages in the image are fixed. If this can't work, I'll just give the fan its own on/off switch.

[image: CircuitIdea]

Comment: yes, use a relay

Comment: by the way, your LED will not light up in your left hand schematic, unless you connect the ground you denoted with the ground symbol to the negative side of your 6 V battery.

Comment: Your inductor and reed switch can be bought as a single component called a "reed relay".

Comment: First, see if you really need a relay and/or total isolation or just two different voltages... See Marcus Muller's answer and the following comments below.

Comment: @Marcus - Yes, it does need to be connected - I put that "ground" symbol there because the image was already so cluttered, and embarrassingly, it slipped my mind  that the symbol doesn't really mean "complete the circuit".  
- I should correct it, but had so much of trouble just uploading it that I'm hesitant to "fiddle around" with another upload...

Comment: @Fredled - Hello! and thanks! - I had seen some items that looked liked combined units, but I couldn't tell whether it would separate the two circuits.
In all honesty, keeping them separate makes it much easier for me to understand.
- Mainly, I'm confused about the things I read that seemed to say inductors are non-functional in Direct Current circuits.  That made no sense to me, because current is of course still *flowing*,so I assumed a magnetic field would exist as long as there was current.
- But the comments ;)  indicate that either what I read was wrong, or probably, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

The inductor doesn't do anything visible to the circuit it's a part of. It does still produce a magnetic field (which will be contained within the shielding of shielded inductors, so you need an unshielded one for this), and that magnetic field can affect other things.

In fact, what you describe is basically a reed relay. These are sold as off-the-shelf parts with the inductor (here called a "coil") and reed switch together in the same package. There are also standard relays, which use larger, more heavy-duty switch contacts and can handle more current.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a 6V DC circuit be configured switch on a second, and separate, 3V DC circuit?

Yes. There's numerous ways to do that: relays, octocouplers, and a few other things are giving you an *isolated* method of switching some current without having any common potential on both sides of the switching element.

Using a slightly less stringent definition of the word "connected", you can use transistors to switch currents if both sides of the switching component agree on some common reference voltage, and thus are "half-connected" (e.g. through a shared ground).

> I had thought that an inductor's magnetic field could be used to close a normally-off reed switch,

You just reinvented the relay!

> an inductor does literally nothing in a DC circuit, as though it's not even there

Well, aside from the wire resistance (which often is very low, so low that you can often consider it to be 0) that's true. Note that this isn't true for the moment you *change* a DC voltage (for example, when turning on or off the controlling 6 V).

Comment: I think transistors would count as a connected circuit. If you need the circuits to remain unconnected (which i'm taking to mean isolated), you need an optocoupler, relay, or some more advanced system involving radio or something.

Comment: @Hearth I'd 100% agree with you on the connected thing, but I'm not sure OP is meaning the same "galvanically separated" definition of "unconnected". More like "there isn't a direct path from A to B aside from the switching element", but you're right, I should be clearer in my wording.

Comment: In this case I don't see the reason why he couldn't use a mosfet with a common ground to power the fan (other than not knowing the technology) and why he would need a galvanic isolation. He could also use a linear voltage regulator if the fan is not too greedy.

Comment: @Fredled I think this is about having a little figurine, that you put somewhere, which turns on the fan or something. The idea here is "magically effecting something a few millimeters away", if I catch OP's drift correctly.

Comment: @Marcus - Yes, re: reed switches.  I've been "investigating" and discovered "reed switches" because the vendor images matched my mental image.
- The two circuits and their parts will be co-located with the others in a space that's 7/8" high, & 2-3/4"X2-7/8". So iInductor & switch will be almost touching. -  Transistors are beyond my learning curve for now, since I'm also learning several new craft techniques, & making-up others as needed.  I do things backwards: I decide what I want to do, & learn whatever I need to do it.  My 'senior' brain just gets tired a bit sooner than it used to ;)

Comment: @Fredled - Hello, and I appreciate the suggestion but that's way past my knowledge level at this point.  
- I need to have the micro-fan separate because I'm running it,and all of the LED sections, off of CR2032 batteries, so the max voltage is 6V, and 320mAH. 
- The house is 1:120 scale; the space for parts is tight.  This unit has a 2-battery holder for the fireplace and a 1-batt for the fan.  I still have the tree to light, that's another 2-batt holder, and two other lighting zones, with 2 more 1-batt holders.  Plus the fan itself, some optical fiber, wiring.... So space is limited ;)

Comment: Thank you to everyone!
I appreciate all of the comments and ideas.  I wish I could try some of the more elaborate ones, but first, I need to finish these holiday things, and then there will be a new year, and time to learn and try new things.
- Since the comments do indicate that this will function, I can go ahead with ordering some parts, especially the *fan* since Newark has it on sale!, and especially, I can go ahead with learning more about driving the inductor, and what size I need to pair with which reed switch.

Comment: Note that I didn't know you are planning to operate a fan from a coin cell. The con cell might not be able to source the current needed to start a fan, even if it has the right voltage.

Comment: Hi Marcus, the fans I'm mainly looking at has a Current Rating of 36mA; the data sheet lists something called "FG Output Current (If)" which is 4mA.  The "tolerance" is listed as "+20% ∕ -30% on rated power and current".
- I don't see info in the data sheet about a startup surge, or anything about an extra current draw at startup.
- I figure I'll just plunk down my $7.70 plus shipping (or maybe go wild and order two!), and test with the battery before I do anything else.
- Even if they don't run off the button cell, I'm forming some other ideas for using them ;)

Comment: That indeed sounds pretty sensible

Comment: @BirdsInMyBrain Transistor MOSFET are easy to use and takes much less room than relays, and waste much less energy. And require soldering skill. It's worth learning. As said, coin cells won't do with a fan and will deplete quickly. I suggest you use on set of batteries for the whole circuit.